# Differentiating in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to use SymPy to differentiate the following equation:

`log(n)**k`

```
import math, sympy
from sympy.abc import x, y, n, k
print(sympy.diff(math.pow(math.log(n, 2), k), n))
```

But I'm getting the `can't convert expression to float` error from SymPy.
What am I doing wrong?

```
runfile('C:/Users/towis/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/towis/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-3728a7ec31a4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/towis/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/towis/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/towis/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(sympy.diff(math.pow(math.log(n,2), k), n))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py", line 226, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")

TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Comment: Please give the entire error message.

Comment: Sure, here you go
Edit: edited the question

Comment: You're most probably getting this error from Python's `math` module as `math.pow` & `math.log` calculate the corresponding floating-point _values_ of the power function and the logarithm. They need _floats_ as input.

Comment: So any way to do it?

Comment: @ToTom, yes, `sympy` provides its own logarithm function, and you can use simple `a ** b` for powers.

Answer (score 1):

As @ForceBru says, use the SymPy functions:

```
>>> diff(log(n, 2)**k, n)
k∗(log(n)/log(2))∗∗k/(n∗log(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your provided code the following way:

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x, y, n, k
print(sympy.diff(sympy.Pow(sympy.log(n, 2),k), n))
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously said, you need to use sympy Functions:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x, y, n, k
print(sp.diff(sp.log(n,2)**k,n)
```

That should do it